# Which statistical test should I use to test results from a genetic algorithm vs. an exact method?

Tags: statistical-significance, genetic-algorithms

I have a known value from some exact algorithm and I have 200 values which were obtained with 200 runs of a genetic algorithm. Now I want to test if on average the results from the GA come from the same distribution as the exact algorithm. So the hypothesis are:

```
H0: GA == Exact value
H1: GA != Exact value
```

Which test should I use z or t test or any other?

Thanks for answers in advance

Answer (score 1):

- Your question is somewhat self-contradictory -- "to test if on average" vs "come from the same distribution" ... are you interested in whether the averages are the same or the distributions are the same?

I suspect you don't really believe that the GA could have *exactly* the same expected value as the exact approach. Any failure to reject the null will be due to insufficient runs, not because they're the same.

To be more specific, I really don't think that a hypothesis test answers an interesting question in this case.

Surely interest would focus on how close it was to the exact values, or whether it was 'close enough' in some sense - that is, I think you really have a measurement issue, not a testing one.